# Impex export and Impex import cronjobs in Hybris

Tags: cron, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

How can I transfer data from one environment to another using impex export and impex import cronjobs through Hybris 6.1 HMC

Answer (score 2):

### Generate the impex export script

Go to `System->Tools->Script Generator`.

In the popin click on <kbd>generate</kbd>. In the textarea you'll then have te export impex for each model.

Copy the models you want to export.

### Export models

Go to `System->Tools->Export`.

Paste the impex copied previously and cick on save. Click on <kbd>next</kbd> then <kbd>start</kbd>.

Download the exported impex and the media if there is one zip file.

### Import models

To import go to `System->Tools->Import`.

Upload a new media (the impex zip downloaded previously).

Click on <kbd>next</kbd>. Upload the media zip. Change the error mode if needed, I prefer use `ignore`.

Finally click on <kbd>start</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you alain.janinm. I was trying to do the same using impex import cronjob and impex export cronjob. Can you kindly let me know how can this same procedure done using cronjobs

Comment: You can do it once using the above procedure. A cronjob will then be created (look for impex export/import job in cronjob admin page) You just have to retrieve the job, rename it and add a trigger. You can also directly create the job (below th search input, you can select the type of cronjob, choose impex export/import). Create it, then in adminitration tab you can upload an impex media with the content to export, or a media input with the data to import.